# Can I use Geometric mean to represent multi-dimensional data for detect outlier?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, statistics, variance, outliers

If I have 3 multi-dimensional data:

```
Data 1: (22, 80, 9)

Data 2: (23, 78, 10)

Data 3: (21, 81, 11)
```

I want to calculate these 3 data’s mean and standard deviation, because I want to detect outlier by 3-sigma rule.

**Can I simply calculate the Geometric mean to represent Data1, Data2 and Data3?**

---

For example:

```
Data 1: (22,80,9) -> Data 1: (25.11414)


Data 2: (23,78,10) -> Data 2: (26.17826)


Data 3: (21,81,11) -> Data 3: (26.54803)
```

After I map the multi-dimensional Data to one-dimensional Data, then I can get variance and standard deviation easily.

The above is my reasoning, but I am not sure about it make sense or not.

Could anybody answer me, or someone have ever seen the paper addressed about this topic,

Very thanks!

Comment: If you map the means of each data to a single vector, and then take the sd or var, then you won't get the whole data sd and variance, but only the sd and variance of the new vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use "3 sigma rule" I will assume that each dimension of your dataset is fixed (in the sense, that it has consistent meaning across data samples), thus:

```
Data 1: (22, 80,  9)
Data 2: (23, 78, 10)
Data 3: (21, 81, 11)
          ^   ^   ^
          |   |   |
  some 1st feature|
              |   |
      second feature
                  |
          third feature
```

You need to estimate **feature wise** stds, thus

```
std1 = std(22, 23, 21)
std2 = std(80, 78, 81)
std3 = std(9,  10, 11)

mu1 = mean(22, 23, 21)
mu2 = mean(80, 78, 81)
mu3 = mean(9,  10, 11)
```

now, when you have a new data point `(x1, x2, x3)` you assume that it is an outlier iff at least one of the following holds

- `x1` does not belong to `[mu1 - 3*std1, mu1 + 3*std1]`
- `x2` does not belong to `[mu2 - 3*std2, mu2 + 3*std2]`
- `x3` does not belong to `[mu3 - 3*std3, mu3 + 3*std3]`

Efficiently, what is happening is that you assume that your data has a univariate, normal distribution feature-wise and that features are conditionally independent, and you simply reject points which have probability less than ~99.7%.

There is no "geometrical mean" involved anywhere.